# Django/AngularJS: CSFR Token Error

Tags: python, angularjs, django, cookies, csrf

I'm new to both Django and AngularJS and I've been struggling on this for hours.

AngularJS Code (of my controller) to POST to Django Server:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/', // This is the Django server IP
    data: {'string': 'body'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     $scope.var= "success";
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.var= response; // To display error. 
     });

    }
})
```

Django Server Code (in view):

```
def index(request):
    return "true"
```

The exact error that I'm getting is:
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ 403 (Forbidden)

Details of error- CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties. Blah blah.

**EDIT**
Would prefer solutions that would work without affecting any of the security provisions of Django

Answer (score 2):

You must include the token csrf in the header of the post call

```
    var csrf ='{{ csrf_token }}';
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken' : csrf },
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/', // This is the Django server IP
        data: {'string': 'body'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         $scope.var= "success";
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.var= response; // To display error. 
         });

        }
    })
```

or excempt csrf token for this call

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have activate cors headers.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return "true"
```

Comment: Yes I've activated cords headers. But isn't there a way to do it without csrf_exempt, since I would like to keep it secure.

Comment: Also even when I try csrf_exempt, it leads to an internal server error